# Calculate difference in throughput between two computers when the time complexity is $2^n$

Tags: computational-complexity

The time complexity for some algorithm is $T(n) = 2^n$ where n is the size of inputs.
A particular computer takes t seconds to process n inputs.
How many inputs can a computer that is 64 times as fast process during the same time t?

How would an equation be set up to solve this?

Comment: Do you mean it takes $t$ seconds to process an input of size $n$? And then the question is what size can be handled in $t$ seconds by the faster computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find $n'$ with 
$$ T(n')=64T(n).$$